# functions on whole numbers that preserve modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ be a function such that for all $x,y,m\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$x\equiv y \pmod m \implies f(x)\equiv f(y) \pmod m.$$ Or in other terms $$f(x) \text{ mod } m = f(x \text{ mod } m) \text{ mod } m$$ My question is

1. Does this property have a name?
2. One example of such functions are polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Are there any other examples? Is there some classification?

Comment: You can rephrase the condition as $x-y \lvert f(x)-f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Is $m$ fixed or not?

Comment: its not. It should hold for all $m$.

Comment: This is the same thing as saying that the function $f:\mathbb Z_m \to \mathbb Z_m$ is well-defined.

Comment: https://www.irif.fr/~seg/_2015SLIDES_Yurifest_Berlin/2015YURIFEST_Berlin.pdf contains many examples and a characterization. They call them "congruence preserving" functions

Comment: @m_t_ Yes, thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for posting such an interesting problem.